# Affecting the whole record value from a CustomField in admin-on-rest

Tags: redux-form, admin-on-rest

I have a Edit component in an [admin-on-rest](https://github.com/marmelab/admin-on-rest)'s app which internally uses [ReduxForm](http://redux-form.com/6.5.0/) and the code looks like this:

```
<Edit {...props} >
    <CustomField />
    <TextInput source="title" />
</Edit>
```

I am wondering how is it possible to change `title` from `CustomField` without persisting it on the on the server?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand exactly what you mean. You want to update the `title` field of your form from ỳour `CustomField`, don't you?

Comment: yeah, that's exactly what I need to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve such a purpose using a custom saga and dispatching the `change` event from `redux-form`. It sounds a little bit complicated told this way, but it is not in reality. :)

First, implement custom sagas to your application:

```
const customSagas = [
    MyCustomEntitySagas,
];

const App = () => (
    <Admin customSagas={customSagas}>
        // ...
    </Admin>
);
```

Then, in your custom saga, just watch an action you will emit from your `CustomField`, something like:

```
import { change } from 'redux-form';
import { put, takeEvery } from 'redux-saga/effects';

import { CUSTOM_FIELD_CHANGE } from './actions';

export function* watchForCustomFieldChange({ payload }) {
    yield put(change('form-record', 'title', payload.newTitle));
}

export default function* root() {
    yield [
        takeEvery(CUSTOM_FIELD_CHANGE, watchForCustomFieldChange),
    ];
}
```

For instance, here is an action creator you may want to dispatch:

```
export const CUSTOM_FIELD_CHANGE = 'CUSTOM_FIELD_CHANGE';

export const customFieldChange = (newTitle) => ({
    type: CUSTOM_FIELD_CHANGE,
    payload: { newTitle },
});
```

The key here is the [Redux Sagas](https://redux-saga.github.io/redux-saga/). Seems a like a lot of boilerplate, but it really eases the development in final.

I tried to be as shortest as possible to prevent from too much noise. But feel free to ask if you need more informations. :)

Comment: thanks for your patience for such an informative answer. This might be a naive question but still I'm having a hard time finding a reference to the dispatch function.

Comment: No problem. It comes from Redux: http://redux.js.org/docs/api/Store.html#dispatch

Comment: @JonathanPetitcolas I would really appreciate it if you could add the dispathing part. I'm new in React Redux and I have problem accessing store.

Comment: And there is a typo, I think `form-record` should be `record-form`